# Why can't I use a switch statement to narrow class types in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, class, type-narrowing

[Playground link with comments](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=3&pln=15&pc=13#code/PTAECZQFwTwBwKYGdQHsBmoEDsoEtYAoHAVwFtQBRXAmAFXgVAG9DRQBBAOQEkBZDgBlQAXlABybvyHiANG1AAFQdzqiJy1XMIBfQoRCgAhtjxkjAG1AALIyhNnL0RsewATG3dAWEAc3tQUABOeABGJFAIhHi4CEHoRgDGTBym5las7Dj4sAyIAFxUNLmMAHRSAoIA3Ao+-oXY5KFxNXoGwHAWJlCeKJ3dzoiuHrYo1gh4vtY9RoEh4ZHRsfFJTIpduCwK2bR5CIXUOfRlmlx0Nezjk9MNTS26+oa+OHF4iVjFMKB49mlOqEFQP1cIRYENDrR1KlHFYAD5KDZQGrtNCIIKzJiobCuD5HQiJLFIHpuVAQ3LWGK+dQACh2sAOnwAlKIAHxbdiGRImUAkJBMMFMbBGIJBVAAd0poAAbngjKAkBKoIlrKBQnYEB4sbjaKU6cdEAoFQRlbTPrrPntmZl2KAuXyikc9qVTnR8gobaAgggoCQgti9aUrlMke7beqHbsyhUhG6PewvT6-drYKU6kgLqA9DpkYZIAKUBhQOhUKg3EhiI0KAAxEtuPbs0B8SgcNRicRNlvadgANUoAHF1OJe33tG1DGr7YkukgUMXAc9sK93sXS-jpyga6WAELh61wEihCxvW2E4IkRJQAHU-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-KirKtAqDg8KopilBACEoAAOrWF82D61rHAWFY95jAhTA3WjAryJbIVAc7bjI+gcTZPKB7xb0xhIan6ebAKpSgJTTBwMKRiAZEgKg1TCiGOgJBY-gWoK8+sghXK+0KxMUDjICcqHX1udTcJsEWGKRgwJH5YJ2JQzts2dC6XBoANcYE9TzP+XNS4Q79nI8qu0g1ioCQFhuNgdtu5DEovfXYB99H4XkNk4iznVJJitiYOL52oAwR-rYHoT8d4eGFL4V+mwT5nwvg-UKucWbIACDFBYCAtbyxQHyBAZAUBHgANb8hhkgSuTAkAEBILMPAWovBP3gRDD2kpCx6nRvDLARFK6dGjkNcCxdS7Ji+BAqBPRJ4oF7v3eB3JoTpGHnKdY3QO6rwYeKSUoChGAVwO-WGMo5SgL1HsSRGE0GgDFACQhHheSSjlEaJUKp6I4OyKUQ0TtrCCzcNNS0DZJbhlYmUdisY4xSxKjLUmTMkEzjNh6UIVV8EZm8faXxiBSr9gCR6IJxNQm1lKKrSKkSbTRKArE+augqhAA)

This is a standard example of type narrowing using `interface`s.

```js
// 2 types of entity
enum EntityType {
  ANIMAL = 'ANIMAL',
  PLANT = 'PLANT',
}

// animal has animal type and has legs attribute
interface Animal {
  entityType: EntityType.ANIMAL;
  legs: number;
}

//plant has plant type and has height attribute
interface Plant {
  entityType: EntityType.PLANT;
  height: number;
}

// generic entity is animal or plant
type Entity = Animal | Plant;

// operate on an entity
const doEntityThing = (entity: Entity) => {
  // can use type narrowing via switch based on entity.entityType
  switch(entity.entityType) {
    case EntityType.PLANT:
      return entity.height;
    case EntityType.ANIMAL:
      return entity.legs;
  }
};
```

Within the switch statement, the type of `entity` is narrowed because each different type that the `entity` can be has a different `entityType`, so TS can tell when, say, `entity.height` is valid or not.

But now here's a similar example using `class`es instead:

```js
// 2 types of foods
enum FoodType {
  MEAT = 'MEAT',
  VEG = 'VEG',
}

// base class for generic food
class FoodBase {
  public constructor(public foodType: FoodType){}
}

// instances of meat class have food type meat and have doneness attribute
class Meat extends FoodBase {
  public static foodType = FoodType.MEAT;
  public readonly foodType = Meat.foodType;

  public constructor(public doneness: 'rare' | 'burnt') {
    super(Meat.foodType);
  }
}

// instances of veg class have food type veg and have organic attribute
class Veg extends FoodBase {
  public static foodType = FoodType.VEG;
  public readonly foodType = Veg.foodType;

  public constructor(public organic: boolean) {
    super(Veg.foodType);
  }
}

// generic food is meat or veg
type Food = Meat | Veg;

// operate on a food
const doFoodThing = (food: Food) => {
  // can use instanceof to narrow the type of the food
  if(food instanceof Meat) {
    console.log(`This meat is ${food.doneness}.`);
  }
  else if(food instanceof Veg) {
    console.log(`This veg is${food.organic ? '' : ' not'} organic.`);
  }

  // can't use switch to narrow type! Why not?
  switch(food.foodType) {
    case FoodType.MEAT:
      console.log(food.doneness); // ERROR HERE!
      break;
    case FoodType.VEG:
      console.log(food.organic); // ERROR HERE!
      break;
  }
};
```

The parameter of the `doFoodThing` function is either a `Meat` or a `Veg`, both of which have different `foodType` attributes. Meat always has foodType 'MEAT' and Veg always has foodType 'VEG', so shouldn't narrowing the argument's foodType down to 'MEAT' mean that the food argument should have a `doneness` attribute? This seems like the same situation as the narrowing of `entity` in the example above. The entity argument was either an `Animal` or a `Plant`, and narrowing the argument's `entityType` worked using a switch statement.

What is different about these two narrowing situations and why does one work while the other doesn't? Is there a way to do this using `class`es and still be able to use a `switch` statement?

Comment: I think a subclass of Meat or Veg would be able to override the type with an unrelated value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because 'foodType' of `Veg` and `Meat` is inferred to type `FoodType`. In order to make it work, you should specify Veg's foodType to FoodType.VEG, Meat's foodType to FoodType.MEAT:

```js
class Meat extends FoodBase {
  public static foodType = FoodType.MEAT as const;
  // Or like this: public static foodType: FoodType.MEAT = FoodType.MEAT;
}

class Veg extends FoodBase {
  public static foodType = FoodType.VEG as const;
  // or like this: public static foodType: FoodType.VEG = FoodType.VEG;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I understand now. Now that I think about it I originally had `public static foodType: FoodType.MEAT;` and that was causing the value to be `undefined` at runtime, so I changed the `:` to an `=` so that it would be initialized. Amidst all the other changes I forgot I had done that. Now I understand why specifying the type and initializing the variable are 2 different things, both of which need to be done. Thanks!